# Whitelabel Error Page opens when button is clicked even though the button works as desired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this interface:

```
export interface DocRow {
    docName: string;
    docDate: string;
    docUrl: string;
    packId: string;
}

interface Props {  
    dRow: DocRow[];
    policy: string;
}

interface State {
    disableIssueButton: boolean;
    showIssueCertPrompt: boolean;
}

export class IssueButton extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    loggingService: LoggingService;
    issueCertService: IssueCertService;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.loggingService = new LoggingService();
        this.issueCertService = new IssueCertService();
        this.state = {
            disableIssueButton: false,
            showIssueCertPrompt: false
        };
    }
 
    showIssue = () => {
        this.setState({ showIssueCertPrompt: true });
    }
 
    hideIssue = () => {
     this.setState({ showIssueCertPrompt: false });
    }
   
    disableIssueButton = () => {
     this.setState({ disableIssueButton: true });
    }

    render() {
        // const { policy } = this.props;
        return this.props.dRow.map(dRow => {
                
            if (dRow.docName === 'Cert') {
        
                return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <Button
                                onClick={this.showIssue}
                                primary={true}
                                fullWidth={false}
                                disabled={this.state.disableIssueButton}
                            >
                                Issue cert
                            </Button>
                            <IssueCert
                                handleClose={this.hideIssue} 
                                disableIssueButton={this.disableIssueButton}
                                showIssueCertPrompt={this.state.showIssueCertPrompt} 
                                policy={this.props.policy}
                                packId={dRow.packId}
                            />
                        </React.Fragment>
                );
            } else {
                return;                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click the button the desired functionality works but also, a new tab opens in my browser at the URL in `DocRow.docUrl`. This page seems to be loading indefinitely and is blank.

Why would this happen when I have added functionality to my button and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My button was inside this:

```
<tr key={docRow.docUrl} className="document-row" onClick={this.onClickOfDoc(packTitle, docRow)}>
```

`onClickOfDoc()` conatins the line `window.open(doc.docUrl, '_blank');`.